# Black and white gradient on surface, where is my red color

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm following the sociamix tutorial and, in the 15 episode, the red color does not apply on my texture. I don't know why I get a black and white gradient only.

[The tutorial](https://youtu.be/_Kc3_b4VgAw)
You can see the result at 19'

[image: Capture from the tutorial]

And here my result :

[image: My result in B & W]

We have created a group to make it easier to manipulate the material.

[My file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18y68CrQnBxtdVuS4Hr_m7sH1HeYwd9uX/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure a factor output should even be able to show red the way he has it set up in that video, or it is possible that this behavior has changed since January.  In one of the next steps he disconnects this factor output and makes a new color output into a Principled shader, so I would just skip ahead to that part, I think.

Comment: Great, the red color appears now. Thanks a lot !